# Transpose a column with duplicates to rows with matching values in an array in VBA

Tags: html, arrays, vba, outlook, transpose

I have a task which I've reached a bit of a block on. I am very new to VBA and am pretty much learning it as I progress with this task

I have 200 emails each containing one html table embedded in the email body

I need to iterate through all the emails and extract data contained in a html table

The table looks like this.

html table data
[image: html table data]

My code so far creates an array to make an identifier for each email i.e. date received property. It then gets the data from within the html table into an array. I have this working, however as the table divides and continues below, the 'new' table headers are being lost in the columns, as it creates an array for the 'top' and 'bottom' table together.

i.e. the table dimensions come up as 26 rows by 23 columns, where as it should be 13 rows by 35 columns (after adding the columns in the table below onto the end of the first table)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i, j, k As Long
Dim creationDate As Date
Dim butaneDatesArr() As Variant 'creating an array to hold the creation date of each email
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim htmlArr() As Variant
Dim table As Object
Dim productsDict As Scripting.Dictionary 'call scripting reference
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element Collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element Collection for td tags
Dim numberofColumns As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim obj1 As Object
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row Elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column Element

Dim a As Object
'Dim htmlTable As htmlTable

Dim headerValues As Variant
Dim headerRow() As String
Dim data() As String
Dim Counter As Integer

Dim numberofRows As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Butane Forward Curves")

For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    Debug.Print Item.Subject
Next

ReDim butaneDatesArr(1 To olFolder.Items.Count, 0)
For i = LBound(butaneDatesArr) To UBound(butaneDatesArr)

    butaneDatesArr(i, 0) = olFolder.Items(i).LastModificationTime

 Next i

 For Each Item In olFolder.Items

    oHTML.Body.innerHTML = Item.HTMLBody
    Set eleColtr = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr") ' gives the number of rows
    Set numberofColumns = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td") ' Get all the td elements in that specific tr
    Set eleColtd = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("td") ' gives total number of elements in the table
```

'build an array for each row/col to store the product names and data

```
    ReDim htmlArr(0 To (eleColtr.Length - 1), 0 To (numberofColumns.Length - 1)) 'set array dimensions 11 by 23, htmlArr(11, 23)
    For j = LBound(htmlArr, 1) To UBound(htmlArr, 1)  'loop through rows dim 0 - 10
            Set ObjTr = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr")(j)

            For k = LBound(htmlArr, 2) To UBound(htmlArr, 2) 'loop over cols 0 - 22

            htmlArr(j, k) = ObjTr.getElementsByTagName("td")(k).innerText

            Next k
    Next j

Next Item

End Sub
```

How can I pivot add the bottom table onto the end of the first table within VBA?
I imagine this is going to be quite fiddly!